# How to character and Numeric values restrict in TextField Java

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

I have two questions regarding character and numeric values limitation. I have listening to focus lost events and validating Name (character) and Contact (numeric) TextFields.

**1.** How do I restrict numeric data less then 3 digits and not allow more then 13 digits.

Below is the coding of my contact TextField for numeric:

```
private void txt_contactFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    if (txt_contact.getText().equals("")) {
    } else {
        String contact = txt_contact.getText();
        Pattern pt6 = Pattern
                .compile("^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+$");
        Matcher mh6 = pt6.matcher(contact);
        boolean matchFound6 = mh6.matches();
        if (!(matchFound6)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "* Enter the Numaric Values only *");
            txt_contact.setText("");
            txt_contact.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

**2.** How do I restrict character data less then 3 character and not allow more then 30 characters.

```
private void txt_nameFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
    if (txt_name.getText().equals("")) {
        error2.setText("Enter Full Name");
        txt_name.setText("");
    } else {
        String name = txt_name.getText();
        Pattern pt1 = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+([\\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$");
        Matcher mh1 = pt1.matcher(name);
        boolean matchFound1 = mh1.matches();
        if (!(matchFound1)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "* Enter the Character Values only *");
            txt_name.setText("");
            txt_name.requestFocus();
        } else {
            error2.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you've posted? I assume it's broken somehow?

Comment: thanks for reply @Duncan Jones .. code is fine but i want to put restrictions on contact and name TextField so user will not enter unlimited characters and digits TextFields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the pattern you can use the statement `{n,m}  n- to m- times`

Duo to this you can build your pattern like this

for your charackter comparison

```
Pattern pt6=Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{3,30}"); // it says, it should be 3-30 non Digits
```

for the numbers it is

```
Pattern pt6=Pattern.compile("\\d{3,13}"); // it says, it should be 3-13 Digits
```

Comment: thanks for reply @Kevin Esche ... the above your character comparison code is working but it is allowing special characters too like @#$% etc ... how i can restrict special characters too....thanks

Comment: oh ok, then just change the `\\D` into `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something easier:

```
NumberFormat numF = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
numF.setMaximumIntegerDigits(13);
numF.setMinimumIntegerDigits(3);
JFormattedTextField THE_FIELD = new JFormattedTextField(numF);
```

(The same idea for *characters*)

Now, only **numbers** are allowed, with the specified length **range**.

Read more about it: [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html)

Comment: +1 nice to see you on another side, but usage of DocumentFilter is better of ways

Comment: Indeed. I've just saw several examples of `DocumentFilter`, looks better. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for reply @MarounMaroun ... can you explain more how i can use it with my above source code...thanks

Comment: @SilentHeart read the links I posted on the answer, they are really good and there are many examples there. Follow them, it's very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

For String

```
public boolean validateString(String data){
        char [] chars = data.toCharArray();
        if(chars.length < 3 || chars.length >13)
            return false;
        return true;
}
```

For Number

```
public boolean validateNumber(int number){
        String data = number+"";
        return validateString(data);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this one. very simple and easy
use the method that you need or both then call where you need pass your JTextField as parameter done...

```
public static void setNumericOnly(JTextField jTextField){
    jTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
           char c = e.getKeyChar();
           if ((!Character.isDigit(c) ||
              (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
              (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
                e.consume();
              }
         }
    });
}

public static void setCharacterOnly(JTextField jTextField){
    jTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
           char c = e.getKeyChar();
           if ((Character.isDigit(c) ||
              (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) ||
              (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
                e.consume();
              }
         }
    });
}
```